# Scrollable SelectableText when selecting text from bottom autoscrolls to top of widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

As shown above when selecting text from a scrollable `SelectableText` Widget it auto scrolls to top initially. Expected behavior is scroll remains in the bottom when text is selected.

I have tried all answers on stackoverflow but it seems this is flutter bug, but if anyone has workaround for it now than it would be great!

You can find code in [this](https://github.com/wilson-christian/flutter_selectable_text_issue.git) github repo.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution or workaround? Have you opened an issue in the flutter git?

Comment: Didn't find an issue so I added it here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96434

Answer (score 3):

With [this merged pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/102270) the issue shall be gone on next flutter release.

Until this release you can add following workaround on `SelectableText.rich` which is not as fluent as the real fix:

```
onSelectionChanged: (selection, cause) {
  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), () {
   _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.offset);
  });
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a short ugly workaround.

Seems that selectable text tries to be sure the cursor/selected text is seen, by jumping to its text field.
In this case when the text field is so big, it jumps to the beginning.

Since in my app I only have long selectable text, without the need to edit it in shorter text fields, I just commented the line that calls jumping when text is selected.

### The Workaround:

In file:
flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart

In function: `userUpdateTextEditingValue`

Comment out the line that calls to: `_scheduleShowCaretOnScreen`

Like this:

```
  @override
void userUpdateTextEditingValue(TextEditingValue value, SelectionChangedCause? cause) {
    // Compare the current TextEditingValue with the pre-format new
    // TextEditingValue value, in case the formatter would reject the change.
    final bool shouldShowCaret = widget.readOnly
      ? _value.selection != value.selection
      : _value != value;
    if (shouldShowCaret) {
      // _scheduleShowCaretOnScreen(); --> This line causes the problem
    }
    _formatAndSetValue(value, cause, userInteraction: true);
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Do you know of any better solutions? Thank you!

Comment: With the merge of https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/102270 this shall be solved on next flutter release

Comment: @RamazanGevrek do you see it fixed? In my project, it is still happening...

Comment: @Johanna I did not recognize that a flutter developer recently revert this fix before it reached stable, after two flutter developer approved change and merged into master.

Comment: But I am not sure if it is fixed otherwise or the fix is fully left out.

Comment: looks like it was left out :(

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. I set the `selectionHeightStyle` parameter to `BoxHeightStyle.includeLineSpacingMiddle` and the problem was solved. I found a solution like this:

```
SelectableText(
        'sample long text...',
        selectionHeightStyle: BoxHeightStyle.includeLineSpacingMiddle,
        
      );
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem. Maybe you had a different problem. I attached here a minimal project to reproduce. You can check your solution with it. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96434